# How can I call 3 tpl.php files in hook_theme function?

Tags: 7, theming

I have 3 tpl/php files and i want to call those .tpl files on the request of user.
where i have given user a dropdown list to select the .tpl files.
I have created dropdown list but i don't know how to call  them on the request of user.

```
/*
 *implements hook_menu().
 */

function dropdown_page_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['page/layout/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Select Layout',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('dropdown_page_select_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */

function dropdown_page_theme(){
    return array(
      'dropdown_page_select_form' => array('render element' => 'form',),
      );
}



function dropdown_page_page(){
  $content[] = l(t('select layout'),'page/layout/%');

  return $content;
}

function dropdown_page_select_form($form, &$form_state){
  $options = array(
    'layout_1' => t('Layout 1'),
    'layout_2' => t('Layout 2'),
    'layout_3' => t('Layout 3'),
    );

  $form['choice'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('Select your layout'),
    );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value'=> t('Go'),
    );
  return $form;
}

function dropdown_page_select_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  drupal_set_message(t('Your layout %input', array('%input' => $form_state['value']['choice'])));
}
```

The detail description is i want to create a page which render list of nodes in a page but i like to give option to user that weather he wants all the node in single column layout or 2 column layout or 3 column layout. For these layout i'm creating 3 different .tpl files so now i want to call them on the request of dropdown list.

```
function dropdown_page_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['page/layout/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Select Layout',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('dropdown_page_select_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */

/*function dropdown_page_theme(){
    return array(
      'dropdown_page_select_form' => array('render element' => 'form',),
      );
}*/

function dropdown_page_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      $theme = array();
      $theme['node__blog_post'] = array(
        'render element' => 'content',
        'base hook' => 'node',
        'template' => 'views-view-unformatted--layout-1--page',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('themes', 'views-view-unformatted--layout-1--page.tpl.php') . '/templates',
       );
      return $theme;

}


function dropdown_page_page(){
  $content[] = l(t('select layout'),'page/layout/%');

  return $content;
}

function dropdown_page_select_form($form, &$form_state){
  $options = array(
    'layout_1' => t('Layout 1'),
    'layout_2' => t('Layout 2'),
    'layout_3' => t('Layout 3'),
    );

  $form['choice'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('Select your layout'),
    );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value'=> t('Go'),
    );
  return $form;
}

function dropdown_page_select_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  drupal_set_message(t('Your layout %input', array('%input' => $form_state['value']['choice'])));
}
```

I'm still not able to call the .tpl.php files

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie with user prefs on form submit.

In the preprocess function for your templates (ie template_preprocess_page), read the cookie value, and depending on the value, prepend the appropriate template to $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'].

Answer (score 0):

You could try `hook_theme` to create template suggestion in module based on user selection

```
<?php
    /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     */
    function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      $theme = array();
      $theme['node__blog_post'] = array(
        'render element' => 'content',
        'base hook' => 'node',
        'template' => 'node--blog_post',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates',
       );
      return $theme;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not able to call views-view-unformatted--layout-1--page.tpl.php file from the templates